# what is the command to be able page up/down a long text?

Tags: command-line, ls

i keep forgetting and I am not sure how to look this up

if for example i want to see the ls commands --help, its very long
i remember there's a command that allows you to  go up and down on the output text - how do i do that?

i tried nano but for some reason it doesn't work as well as i thought it did

(also PS
the command i am looking for ls is to see hidden files, if u want you could tell me what that is on the way)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean but when you do

```
man ls
```

you can use following commands:

space to advance one page

d to advance half a page

b to go back one page

u to go back half a page

arrow keys to go up/down with one line at a time

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output into `less`, for example

```
ls --help | less
```

Use `q` to quit `less`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Shift+PgUp and Shift+PgDn to scroll the output in your terminal.

Or you can pipe your output to less, e.g.:

```
ls --help | less
```

then you can scroll with cursor up/down.

And the command you are actually looking for is `ls -A` to show all files.

Comment: thank you! exactly what i was looking.. ill try to remember it by saying "less is more" haha